# How to use lpdspooler Java library to intercept print job requests?

Tags: java, printing, daemon

Here is a very rough sketch of what I am trying to set up.

[image: Schematic]

There are at least 2 questions asking more or less the same thing.

(1) [How to intercept data being sent to a printer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034340/how-to-intercept-data-being-sent-to-a-printer)

(2) [Intercepting data sent to printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041603/intercepting-data-sent-to-printer)

(1) does have an answer, which is a link to the lpdspooler library for Java: http://lpdspooler.sourceforge.net

However my question is now how exactly do I interface with this Java library to begin intercepting print requests--ideally an example .java file would be good.  I am sure it would be immediately obvious for many programmers, but I have no versing in low level tasks like printing.

Comment: Actually, the first Question >>does<< have an Answer.  And that Answer is basically the only practical approach ... replace the standard daemon with something that does what you want it to do.  The Answer is directly applicable to Mac OS X, because Mac OS X uses (or can use) `lpd`.

Comment: I must have skimmed too quickly over the first question referenced, I wrongly saw that it wasn't marked as the accepted answer.  I was hoping for a higher level library--unsure why my initial searches didn't turn up very much on this topic.  If that is the only option then my question is redundant.

Comment: I'd be amazed if someone wrote and published a library for printer request interception.  It is too specialized a use-case.  And besides, that would only work for programs that *used* the library to talk to the printer.  Your Question is asking for something that works for all print requests ... not just requests from applications that you've modified to use a different printer library.